# ngModel is not binding properly

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, angular-forms

I'm trying to manipulate the value from an input because I want to extract the value that exceeds the desired length from it.

In this example, I want to keep with 3 characters and extract the rest. For that, I used `(ngModelChange)` and `[ngModel]`.

**html**

```
<input type="text"
 [ngModel]="value"
 (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
```

**ts**

```
onChange(e: string) {
    if (e.length > 3) {
      this.value= e.substring(0, 3);
      this.input.nativeElement.value = this.value;
    }
  }
```

It works once, but If I continue changing the input, I'm able to put more character and the input value is not updated anymore. **Why does that happen? Why the `value` from the input is not updated anymore?**

I solved using `nativeElement`. But I still would like to know why It doesn't work with `[ngModel]`.

I replicated it on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-mask)

Comment: I think you forgot to add round braces [(ngModel)]="value"

Comment: I split the ngModel because I just wanna used the `ngModelChange` once. Because `ngModel` is the simplified way to `[ngModel]="value" (ngModelChange)="value = $event"`.

Comment: do you want the user to input values and restrict further input ? Look at custom directives. You can make a directive that will keep the user to input more than 3 characters.

Comment: Its an interesting behavior. Please put a solution if you find one.

Comment: Why don't you use the input limit on your html? there is `maxLength="X"` you could use to prevent the user entering more of it

Answer (score 1):

You could also use reactive forms, to have access to the `valueChanges` `Observable`. This would allow you to add useful operators like `debounceTime` and `distinctUntilChanged`, which provide a richer user experience.

[Reactive Forms - valueChanges](https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-valuechanges/)

Answer (score 1):

> Why does that happen? Why the value from the input is not updated anymore?

I guess this is something related to Angular change detection, when component data changes, and app tries to re-render the view to reflect that change. `ngModelChange` is event emitter and in this case, you're trying to update model immediately before change detection can detect and implement the change.
As a workaround `setTimeout` might be used:

```
onChange2(e: string) {
  console.warn('E input-2 : ', e);
  if (e.length > 3) {
    setTimeout(()=> {
      this.valor2 = e.substring(0, 3);
    });
    console.log('here 2', this.valor2);
  }
}
```

Also, you need to use two-way binding `[(ngModel)]="valor2"` in template to update view, when model get updated. Here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-mask-958cgr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

so I went ahead to change 2 things in your code:

1. `[ngModel]` to `[(ngModel)]`
2. added a `(keyup)` binding

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-mask-ytq93a)

Comment: the only part I was not clear about was
_I want to keep with 3 characters and extract the rest_.
Even in the native element example you cannot enter more than 4th character.

Comment: My idea is to use 4th to populate another input.

Comment: I love feedback and would like if the downvoter explains the downvote.

Comment: @VictorHenrique great, so my solution gives you the fourth one and then replaces the input text with the substring. does that work for you?

Comment: It wasn't my vote. I liked the solution, unfortunately, It is slower than that one I use `native element` and the user can see that I'm "cutting" the string. Besides, It doesn't explain why the `[ngModel]` do not works if I continue changing the input.

Comment: @VictorHenrique fair enough, I'll work on finding a better solution and if the original erroneous behavior has a cause to it.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following to achieve what you needed...

only one **HTML** change

```
<input type="text"
 [(ngModel)]="valor2"
 [maxLength]="3"
 >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to see whether `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` is used in your component. If it is true, then use method `markForCheck();` to update your UI in .

For example:

```
constructor(public cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

onChange(e: string) {      
   if (e.length > 3) {
       this.value= e.substring(0, 3);
       this.cd.markForCheck();
   }
}
```

or try to detect changed in `ngOnInit()`:

```
ngOnInit() {
  setInterval(() => {
    this.cd.markForCheck();
  }, 3000);
}
```